# 9000 rows affected message, but no rows actually changed

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm having a problem with MySQL. When I run the code below, via *phpmyadmin*:

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
    SET post_content = REPLACE
        (
        post_content,
        '31.media.tumblr.com/',
        '41.media.tumblr.com/'
        ) 
    WHERE post_content LIKE '%31.media.tumblr.com/%' 
    AND post_content NOT LIKE '%.gif%';
```

It returns:

> 9000 rows affected

If I make a search, it shows that it replaced all the needed things successfully. But if I go and hit the 'EDIT' option in *phpmyadmin* on one of the rows inside the `post_content` column, no changes are done inside it; everything stays the same.

**What might be the reason?**

For me there's something wrong with the code above. Maybe it returns `NULL` or something and stops the update. If I remove this part:

```
AND post_content NOT LIKE '%.gif%';
```

...it does work properly.

The database is a default WordPress one:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Example of data inside `post_content`:

```xml
<p>some text</p>
<img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/eet1r5co8so1/tumblr_mzlt6zqeet1r5co8so1.gif" alt="" />
<img src="http://11.media.tumblr.com/L4B1q/tumblr_ml5i2cGL4B1qz4fjqo1.gif" alt="" />
other text
<img src="http://51.media.tumblr.com/n42sryL4JG1rda3bfo1/tumblr_n42sryL4JG1rda3bfo1.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/eet1r5co8so1/tumblr_noui3gHzxp1qfvouao1_1280.jpg" alt="" />
some other text
...
```

Comment: You're trying to `REPLACE` where post_content `LIKE '%31.media.tumblr.com/% AND post_content NOT LIKE '%.gif%''` but in your test there aren't any rows like `%31.media%` and not like `%.gif%`. The only one is `http://31.media.tumblr.com/eet1r5co8so1/tumblr_mzlt6zqeet1r5co8so1.gif` and it doesn't match with the condition.

Comment: I expect to change all `31.media.tumblr.com/` urls with `41.media.tumblr.com/ ` except `31.media.tumblr.com/` urls that contain `.gif` in them, they stay 31 and don't change!

Comment: the urls above are examples... I've 9k rows matching `31.media.tumblr.com` in `post_content` ending in both .jpg & .gif

Comment: Your problem is that you need to parse the whole `post_content` column text. This is probably not doable in MySQL, not even with its regexes (which have limitations.) I suggest you use a script that gets the text from mysql, parses it, makes the changes and then updates the rows.

Comment: If you can replace MySQL with MariaDB, you could use the improved regex functionalities, i.e. the [REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/regexp_replace/) function.

Answer (score -1):

I did the same as you did and it worked.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO `test`.`wp_posts` (`idws_posts`, `post_content`) VALUES ('1', '<img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/eet1r5co8so1/tumblr_mzlt6zqeet1r5co8so1.gif" alt="" />');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `test`.`wp_posts` (`idws_posts`, `post_content`) VALUES ('2', '<img src="http://11.media.tumblr.com/L4B1q/tumblr_ml5i2cGL4B1qz4fjqo1.gif" alt="" />');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `test`.`wp_posts` (`idws_posts`, `post_content`) VALUES ('3', '<img src="http://51.media.tumblr.com/n42sryL4JG1rda3bfo1/tumblr_n42sryL4JG1rda3bfo1.jpg" alt="" />');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `test`.`wp_posts` (`idws_posts`, `post_content`) VALUES ('4', '<img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/eet1r5co8so1/tumblr_noui3gHzxp1qfvouao1_1280.jpg" alt="" />');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> SELECT * FROM test.wp_posts;
+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| idws_posts | post_content                                                                                       |
+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|          1 | <img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/eet1r5co8so1/tumblr_mzlt6zqeet1r5co8so1.gif" alt="" />        |
|          2 | <img src="http://11.media.tumblr.com/L4B1q/tumblr_ml5i2cGL4B1qz4fjqo1.gif" alt="" />               |
|          3 | <img src="http://51.media.tumblr.com/n42sryL4JG1rda3bfo1/tumblr_n42sryL4JG1rda3bfo1.jpg" alt="" /> |
|          4 | <img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/eet1r5co8so1/tumblr_noui3gHzxp1qfvouao1_1280.jpg" alt="" />   |
+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> UPDATE test.wp_posts 
    ->     SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'31.media.tumblr.com/','41.media.tumblr.com/') 
    ->     WHERE post_content LIKE '%31.media.tumblr.com/%' AND post_content NOT LIKE '%.gif%';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql>         
mysql> SELECT * FROM test.wp_posts;
+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| idws_posts | post_content                                                                                       |
+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|          1 | <img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/eet1r5co8so1/tumblr_mzlt6zqeet1r5co8so1.gif" alt="" />        |
|          2 | <img src="http://11.media.tumblr.com/L4B1q/tumblr_ml5i2cGL4B1qz4fjqo1.gif" alt="" />               |
|          3 | <img src="http://51.media.tumblr.com/n42sryL4JG1rda3bfo1/tumblr_n42sryL4JG1rda3bfo1.jpg" alt="" /> |
|          4 | <img src="http://41.media.tumblr.com/eet1r5co8so1/tumblr_noui3gHzxp1qfvouao1_1280.jpg" alt="" />   |
+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Are not you missing something?

Comment: I really don't know. I'm trying to get it to work for 3 days straight now. like I said... it says `9000 rows affected`... but when I hit EDIT (in phpmyadmin) nothing has changed... same when I try to get the data from the table with php... the output isn't changed.

Comment: Did you try from other client, like `MySQL Workbench`?

Comment: yes, nothing changes, unfortunately.  

btw the test you made above... doesn't have the <img> tags..

Answer (score -2):

Is your MySQL on auto-commit? If not, try immediately after the update to run a commit statement.
What I think it is happening is that when you run an update statement from phpMyAdmin you are actually inside a SESSION. If you do not run the statement: COMMIT; when you go outside the SESSION everything gets rolled-back

Comment: Imma try. But I don't it's that, tho, because if I remove the code without `AND post_content NOT LIKE '%.gif%';` the script works just fine.

Comment: Then what about adding in the first like statement the second one. Something similar to: WHERE post_content LIKE '%31.media.tumblr.com/%.jpg%'

Comment: nope, that didn't worked... it changed all the 31 to 41.. not only .jpg's